# How Best to Handle Iterating Over Sub-Data in Angular App

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, angular, iteration

In my Angular app with a MongoDB/Node backend, I have been successfully iterating over an array of records and printing them to the view in a table layout - one line per object in the array.

Now I have a situation where I need to break out what was information on one line into *three* lines, based on info in a "subdata" object. A simplified version of the data looks like this:

```
data: [
    {
        name: {
           first: "John,
           last: "Smith
         },
        referred: true,
        birthDate: date,
        city: "New York",
        createDate: date,
        subdata: {
            a: "value a",
            b: "value b",
            c: "value c"
        },
        deleted: false
    }
 ]
```

Rather than iterating once for each object in the "data" array, which I was doing before like this:

```
<tr *ngFor="let record of records.data | paginate: { id: 'results', itemsPerPage: 12, currentPage: getPageNumber(), totalItems: records.count }">
```

... I instead need to now print three lines - one for each of the values in the "subdata" object. But each of those lines needs to include the name, the birthDate, and the city that is part of the parent object.

From an architectural point of view, does it make it more sense to create a new backend endpoint, and populate the data in the format I want to iterate over it by (which would involve some repetition of props and values (name, birthDate, city, etc...), like this:

```
reOrgedData: [
  {
    name: {
      first: "John,
      last: "Smith
    },
    referred: true,
    birthDate: date,
    city: "New York",
    createDate: date,
    a: value
    deleted: false
  },
  {
    name: {
      first: "John,
      last: "Smith
    },
    referred: true,
    birthDate: date,
    city: "New York",
    createDate: date,
    b: value
    deleted: false
  },
  {
    name: {
      first: "John,
      last: "Smith
    },
    referred: true,
    birthDate: date,
    city: "New York",
    createDate: date,
    c: value
    deleted: false
  }
]
```

or is there a way I can iterate over this in its original data structure, but still break it out into three lines in the view?

My sense is that creating a custom endpoint with the data organized in the form I need is the way to go, even though that does involve some repetition. This approach makes for less hoops-jumping on the front-end. But I am curious for people's take on what would be the best approach in a scenario like this.